# How to remove the square brackets from the Array Variable

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

I have an array coming as a result of for each loop as shown below.

```
[
    {
        "cont": "",
        "productIdSAT": "53131602",
        "qunt": "1",
        "srvcId": "PACKETS",
        "volH": "22",
        "volL": "17.5",
        "volW": "27",
        "weight": "1"
    },
    {
        "cont": "",
        "productIdSAT": "53131602",
        "qunt": "1",
        "srvcId": "PACKETS",
        "volH": "22",
        "volL": "17.5",
        "volW": "27",
        "weight": "1"
    },
    {
        "cont": "",
        "productIdSAT": "53131602",
        "qunt": "1",
        "srvcId": "PACKETS",
        "volH": "22",
        "volL": "17.5",
        "volW": "27",
        "weight": "1"
    }
]
```

How to remove the square brackets as I need to assign the output without square brackets to different json payload.

I have tried using **replace(replace(string(outputs('Compose')),'[',''),']','')**
But it removes the brackets but again converts the data into string like this

```
"{\"cont\":\"\",\"productIdSAT\":\"53131602\",\"qunt\":\"1\",\"srvcId\":\"PACKETS\",\"volH\":\"22\",\"volL\":\"17.5\",\"volW\":\"27\",\"weight\":\"1\"},{\"cont\":\"\",\"productIdSAT\":\"53131602\",\"qunt\":\"1\",\"srvcId\":\"PACKETS\",\"volH\":\"22\",\"volL\":\"17.5\",\"volW\":\"27\",\"weight\":\"1\"},{\"cont\":\"\",\"productIdSAT\":\"53131602\",\"qunt\":\"1\",\"srvcId\":\"PACKETS\",\"volH\":\"22\",\"volL\":\"17.5\",\"volW\":\"27\",\"weight\":\"1\"}"
```

I have tried to convert it to Json but when i use the expression it is only converting and instead of 3 items it is giving ouput as

```
{
        "cont": "",
        "productIdSAT": "53131602",
        "qunt": "1",
        "srvcId": "PACKETS",
        "volH": "22",
        "volL": "17.5",
        "volW": "27",
        "weight": "1"
    },
```

but output expected

```
 {
        "cont": "",
        "productIdSAT": "53131602",
        "qunt": "1",
        "srvcId": "PACKETS",
        "volH": "22",
        "volL": "17.5",
        "volW": "27",
        "weight": "1"
    },
    {
        "cont": "",
        "productIdSAT": "53131602",
        "qunt": "1",
        "srvcId": "PACKETS",
        "volH": "22",
        "volL": "17.5",
        "volW": "27",
        "weight": "1"
    },
    {
        "cont": "",
        "productIdSAT": "53131602",
        "qunt": "1",
        "srvcId": "PACKETS",
        "volH": "22",
        "volL": "17.5",
        "volW": "27",
        "weight": "1"
    }
```

Please let me know how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON standard does not let you have an object with that output you need. But, if you are thinking to have the result as an string, my suggestion is

```js
let data = [
    {
        "cont": "",
        "productIdSAT": "53131602",
        "qunt": "1",
        "srvcId": "PACKETS",
        "volH": "22",
        "volL": "17.5",
        "volW": "27",
        "weight": "1"
    },
    {
        "cont": "",
        "productIdSAT": "53131602",
        "qunt": "1",
        "srvcId": "PACKETS",
        "volH": "22",
        "volL": "17.5",
        "volW": "27",
        "weight": "1"
    },
    {
        "cont": "",
        "productIdSAT": "53131602",
        "qunt": "1",
        "srvcId": "PACKETS",
        "volH": "22",
        "volL": "17.5",
        "volW": "27",
        "weight": "1"
    }
];

let text = JSON.stringify(data);
let output = text.replace(/\[|\]/g,'');
```

if you are going to use javascript, that could be the way.

My test

[image]

But at the end, if you want to use the result (output) as a JSON object I think this is not useful.

Hope this help a little bit

Comment: Thanks So Much I have resolved it the json payload where I am trying to add my array I removed the brackets and just assigned my array variable it worked fine

Comment: Excellent, if you show the process, that can help others. Thanks for feedback